# Using CASE to Mark No If No Results From SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

is it possible to print "no" if no result found

```
SELECT mobileno,  
 CASE
    WHEN region = '1234' 
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'NO'
  END  
FROM subscriber
WHERE region = '1234'
and  status = 1
and mobileno in (77777,88888)
```

Currently it only print 1 row like

77777,yes

but i want like following

```
77777,yes
88888,no
```

Update: One mobileno like 7777 may belongs from two regions then 7777 will get print with NO and YES in two rows if we remove region condition.

Sample Data

```
sr.No, Name, mobileno, region, status
1,     abc,  77777,    1234,    1
2,     xyz,  88888,    1222,    1
3,     tyu,  22342,    9898,    1
4,     abc,  77777,    8787,    1
```

Sample OutPut

```
77777, Yes
88888, No
```

Comment: You want to fetch a row when no row is found - um, no that's not possible.

Comment: You are fetching the **WHERE region = '1234'** always which is causing the CASE to always go in **WHEN** condition

Comment: **Please provide the create and insert statements and show your desired output.**

Answer (score 2):

You can 'create' a table by selecting from dual, and left joining :

```
SELECT t.dummy_num,
       CASE WHEN s.mobileno is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end
FROM (SELECT 77777 as dummy_num from dual
      UNION select 88888 from dual) t
LEFT JOIN subscriber s
 ON(t.dummy_num = s.mobileno and s.region = '1234' and s.status = 1 )
```

Edit: you can also do it dynamically like this:

```
SELECT t.mobileno,
       CASE WHEN s.mobileno is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end
FROM (select distinct mobileno from subscriber) t
LEFT JOIN subscriber s
 ON(t.mobileno= s.mobileno and s.region = '1234' and s.status = 1 )
WHERE t.mobileno IN(777,888,.....)
```

Comment: Good solution . +1

Comment: mobileno will not be 7777 or 8888 only, i have list which containts upto 900 mobileno, so mobileno list will vary time to time

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan Updated

Comment: @sagi above mentioned solution is not working, it prints "7777,yes" two times